# Triple-quoted string literal recognized as docstring undesirably by sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

In one of my `__init__.py` file:

```
description="""
This is a package for blablahblah.

It contains blahblah.
"""
```

The string variable is just for the purpose of usage in other modules and I don't want it to be recognized by `sphinx` and extracted out as documentation. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Try putting an empty string before it. Then sphinx should extract that as documentation instead.

Comment: could you be a little more specific? thanks.

Comment: A quick look at the Sphinx documentation says that this shouldn't be happening. You're sure Sphinx thinks this is a docstring?

Comment: Sphinx uses the first string in the module as documentation. So declare an empty string before you declare the description string. Sphinx will pull out the empty string as documentation, and description will still be accessible as normal.

Comment: I don't believe that Sphinx is using that as documentation. Sphinx should only use string *literals*, it doesn't look into assignments.

Comment: seeing your comments, I looked at the code more carefully. It turns out that there is a hidden line adding `description` to `__doc__`. I guess that is the problem. thanks, all.

Comment: @RNA Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is caused by a stupid mistake:

One "buried" line of code added the `description` to the `__doc__` variable.